# Is there a GAN that can be used for sequence prediction?

Tags: deep-learning, applications, prediction, generative-adversarial-networks

I want to use a GAN for sequence prediction, in a similar way that we use RNNs for sequence prediction. I want to test its performance in comparison with RNNs. Is there a GAN that can be used for sequence prediction?

Comment: A sequence-to-sequence model may be what you were looking for.